# gcc linker errors when using boost to_lower & trim

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm trying to use the boost library in my code but get the following linker errors under Sparc Solaris platform.

The problem code can essentially be summarised to:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string xparam;

... 
xparam = boost::to_lower(xparam);
```

The linker error is:

```
LdapClient.cc:349: no match for `std::string& = void' operator
/opt/gcc-3.2.3/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/basic_string.h:338: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/opt/gcc-3.2.3/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/basic_string.h:341:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/opt/gcc-3.2.3/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/basic_string.h:344:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
gmake: *** [LdapClient.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a linker error, it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`boost::to_lower`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_lower.html) does not return a copy of the string, it operates on the variable passed into the function. For some examples, [read this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html).

So no need to reassign:

```
boost::to_lower(xparam);
```

You will get an error because you are trying to assign the string to the value `void`.

If you want to make a copy of it, use the copy version:

```
std::string xparamLowered = boost::to_lower_copy(xparam);
```

Comment: doh! must have been a late night.  Cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::to_lower` [modifies the string in-place](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_lower.html), it does not return a new string. This is sufficient:

```
boost::to_lower(xparam);
```

And your code doesn't compile because the return type of `to_lower` is `void` (as the error message says).